# How to print out a reversed array using range?

Tags: c#, range, c#-8.0

Currently I'm sort of playing with this new `c# 8.0` feature which is [ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges).

And so far I have a question. Am I allowed to create a `range` from the end to the beginning ?

Lets say I have an `array` and I would like to print it out in reversed direction via `range`:

```
static void Test()
{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) array[i] = i;
    Range range = ^1..0;

    foreach (int v in array[range]) WriteLine(v);
}
```

But it gets me a runtime error - `System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'` So am I right that the only one direction(from the beginning to the end) is allowed for `ranges` ?

Comment: All the examples are of increasing ranges.  To create a decreasing range you'd somehow have to set a step of `-1` (default is `+1`), and the C# syntax doesn't seem to include a way to specify step.  (For example, MATLAB uses `a:b` for incrementing ranges and `b:step:a` for ranges with a step of your choice, thus `b:-1:a` is a decrementing range)

Comment: [This document](https://www.infoq.com/articles/cs8-ranges-and-recursive-patterns) describes a step syntax: `a..b:step`.   However, the `System.Range` type doesn't appear to be able to support a custom step.

Comment: @BenVoigt the article you posted appears to be just a proposal, so many of its features are not present in C#8 current release, like step and foreach with ranges. Maybe they will be implemented, maybe not.

Comment: @Magnetron yes, fair enough

Comment: I wish Microsoft would use `offset` instead of `index` and `stride` instead of `step`. There is already enough confusion out there among languages that support slicing like Fortran/Python/Matlab etc.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse ranges are not so much a limitation on the `Range` type, but rather a limitation on the `Span` (and related) types – which assume a positive increment. The rational is that many of the low-level optimizations and usage scenarios for a *slice* of an array are only geared toward the basic notion of a "pointer plus size". ([Link to Range usages in Framework](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Range.cs,6dde223299b52fdd,references))

While this won't allow a reverse `Span` to be passed around, an extension method could be used to provide an easy and *performant* syntax for reverse range enumeration:

```
public static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static int Normalize(this Index index, int length) => 
           index.IsFromEnd ? length - index.Value : index.Value;

    public static (int start, int end) Normalize(this Range range, int length) => 
           (range.Start.Normalize(length), range.End.Normalize(length));

    public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(this T[] items, Range range)
    {
        var (start, end) = range.Normalize(items.Length);

        return start <= end ? items[range] : GetRangeReverse();

        IEnumerable<T> GetRangeReverse()
        {
            for (int i = start; i >= end; i--)
                yield return items[i];
        }
    }
}

...

var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();

foreach (var num in numbers.Enumerate(^3..1))
    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: The property name changed to `IsFromEnd` [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index.isfromend?view=netcore-3.0)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find anything that says that's possible. But, it doesn't appear to be a language restriction, as we can create a range like `Range r = 5..1;` and that doesn't throw exceptions, so it must be the implementation of `Array[Range]` and other types, like string that doesn't accept it. That put, you can probably create an method that accepts a `Range` and does what you want.

Edit: I made the following method that works with arrays:

```
static T[] MySlice<T>(T[] array, Range r)
{
    //Transforms indexes "from end" to indexes "from start"    
    if(r.Start.IsFromEnd){
        var startIdx = array.Length - r.Start.Value;
        r = new Range(startIdx,r.End);
    }
    if(r.End.IsFromEnd){
        var endIdx = array.Length - r.End.Value;
        r = new Range(r.Start,endIdx);
    }
    //Check if start value is greater than end value. If so, invert it
    if(r.Start.Value > r.End.Value)
    {                
        r = new Range(r.End,r.Start);
        var invArr = array[r];
        Array.Reverse(invArr);
        return invArr;
    }
    return array[r];
}
```

And you can use like

```
int[] arr = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToArray();
Range r = ^0..0;

foreach(var v in MySlice(arr,r)){
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: you can do `r.Start.ToString()[0] == '^'` more simplier with `r.Start.FromEnd`

Comment: and also you're getting a copy of array here `var invArr = array[r];` you need to do with `span` - `var invArr = array.AsSpan()[r];`

Comment: @isxaker about the second comment, if you want to return an array, then you can't use `Span` or you'll have to convert the `Span` to `Array`, which would result in no gain in using the `Span`. What could made a difference is if we change the return type to `IEnumerable` or `Span`, but that's up to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var range = array[0..5];

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", range));

var rev = range.AsEnumerable().Reverse();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", rev));
```

Will produce

```
 1,2,3,4,5
 5,4,3,2,1
```

I believe this required both C# 8.0 and System.Linq

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution (written as extension method so include in static class)

```
/// <summary>
///     Filters an enumeration by only returning the items in the <paramref name="range">specified range</paramref>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">The source enumeration</param>
/// <param name="range">The range</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The item type</typeparam>
/// <returns>A enumeration the only includes the <paramref name="range" />.</returns>
/// <remarks>
///     <para>
///         Attempts to efficiently apply a <see cref="Range" /> to any enumeration, not just
///     </para>
///     <para>
///         Supports reverse ranges, i.e. where the <see cref="Range.Start" /> is greater than <see cref="Range.End" />.
///         However, in such an instance,
///         the  <see cref="Range.Start" /> is exclusive and the  <see cref="Range.End" /> is inclusive, so that `^0..0`
///         indicates the full, reverse range; and `2..0` will return item 1, followed by item 0.
///     </para>
/// </remarks>
```

This goes further by supporting the range method on any enumerable, and is used like:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
Range range = ^0..0;

foreach (int v in array.Span(range)) WriteLine(v);
```

Note only does it support reversal, it works with *any* enumerable.

**HOWEVER** It highlights a problem with `Range` itself.  How do you specify *all* items in *reverse*?

The spec for span says the *start* is *inclusive* and the end is *exclusive*.   Also, both are `System.Index`s, and as such *do not support negative*.  Finally, the `^1` index refers to the 'last' item, with `^0` indicating an index outside the enumeration (beyond the end).

Therefore the `..` (all) range is equivalent to `0..^0`.

The reverse of all, should be `^1..-1`, as the start is `inclusive` and the end `exclusive`, meaning we have to specify the index 'after' 0, which in reverse is `-1`. ***BUT** `-1` is not a valid `Index`*

So we have to use `^0..0` to indicate the reverse all. This means when specifying a reverse range, the start is *exclusive* and the end is *inclusive*.  That is the solution I adopt with the above method.

Comment: You didn't post the code for your extension method, only the comment documentation.